# (Spring Boot + JWT) how to get JWT in response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I want to get the JWT in respose when I hit '/login'. But I am missing something and can't figure it out.

Following is my code:

**SecurytiApplication.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.securyti")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.securyti")
@SpringBootApplication
public class SecurytiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecurytiApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.example.securyti.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.example.securyti.security.UserAccountService;
import com.example.securyti.security.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import com.example.securyti.security.jwt.JwtAuthorizationFilter;
import com.example.securyti.security.jwt.JwtTokenService;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    protected JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    protected JwtAuthorizationFilter JwtAuthorizationFilter;

    @Autowired
    protected UserAccountService userAccountService;

    @Autowired
    protected JwtTokenService jwtTokenService;

    @Autowired
    protected ConfigurationService configService; 

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationManager();
        jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager,
            jwtTokenService, (BCryptPasswordEncoder) passwordEncoder(), userAccountService);

        JwtAuthorizationFilter = new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager, 
                configService, jwtTokenService);
        http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register")
                .permitAll()                
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter).addFilter(JwtAuthorizationFilter);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
          throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userAccountService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

**JwtAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
package com.example.securyti.security.jwt;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import com.example.securyti.security.UserAccount;
import com.example.securyti.security.UserAccountService;

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
      private final JwtTokenService jwtTokenService;
      private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
      private final UserAccountService userAccountService;

      public JwtAuthenticationFilter(
          final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
          final JwtTokenService jwtTokenService,
          final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
          final UserAccountService userAccountService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtTokenService = jwtTokenService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userAccountService = userAccountService;
      }

      @Override
      public Authentication attemptAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest req,
          final HttpServletResponse res) {

        String jwt = jwtTokenService.getTokenFromRequest(req);
        UserAccount userAccount = null;

        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && jwtTokenService.validateToken(jwt)) {
            userAccount = (UserAccount) userAccountService.loadUserByUsername(jwtTokenService.getUsernameFromJWT(jwt));

        }

        if(userAccount == null){
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
        }
        AbstractAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userAccount.getUsername(),
                userAccount.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList());
        Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);
        return auth;
      }

      private String getUsername(final UserAccount creds) {
        if (creds != null) {
          return creds.getUsername();
        }
        return null;
      }



      @Override
      protected void successfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest req,
          final HttpServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain,
          final Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final UserAccount account = (UserAccount) auth.getPrincipal();
        jwtTokenService.addTokenToResponse(account, res);

        super.successfulAuthentication(req, res, chain, auth);
      }


}
```

**JwtAuthorizationFilter.java**

```
package com.example.securyti.security.jwt;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import com.example.securyti.config.ConfigurationService;

public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    private ConfigurationService configService;
    private JwtTokenService jwtTokenService;

    public JwtAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager, ConfigurationService configService, 
            final JwtTokenService jwtTokenService) {
        super(authManager);
        this.configService = configService;
        this.jwtTokenService = jwtTokenService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(configService.getHeaderField());

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(configService.getTokenPrefix())) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(configService.getHeaderField());
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = jwtTokenService.getUsernameFromJWT(token);

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**JwtTokenService.java** (This is just the helper class)

```
package com.example.securyti.security.jwt;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import com.example.securyti.config.ConfigurationService;
import com.example.securyti.security.UserAccount;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException;

@Service
public class JwtTokenService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenService.class);

    private ConfigurationService configurationService;

    public JwtTokenService(final ConfigurationService configurationService) {
        super();
        this.configurationService = configurationService;
    }

    String getTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader(configurationService.getHeaderField());
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith(configurationService.getTokenPrefix())) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addTokenToResponse(UserAccount account, HttpServletResponse res) {

        LocalDateTime expiry = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(configurationService.getJwtExpirationInSec());

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(account.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(Date.from(expiry.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, configurationService.getJwtSecret())
                .compact();
        res.addHeader(configurationService.getHeaderField(), configurationService.getTokenPrefix() + token);
    }

    public String getUsernameFromJWT(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(configurationService.getJwtSecret())
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        return claims.getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(configurationService.getJwtSecret()).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature");
        } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Expired JWT token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= root

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

#TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF
logging.level.root=DEBUG

## JWT
jwt.secret= JWTSuperSecretKey
jwt.expirationInSec = 10
jwt.tokenPrefix = Bearer 
jwt.headerField = Authorization
```

There is no handler method '\login' in controller. Currently when I hit the '/login' with valid username and password I get 403 with following message on console:

```
Bad credentials
    at com.example.securyti.security.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:58)
```

What am I missing. Please correct me if my understanding happen to be wrong somewhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose probably use Spring Cloud security with JWT token is a more suitable choice. For your use case you should configure an authorization server and this job is very simple in spring cloud security the server will be a spring boot app like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class SecurityOAuth2AutorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public SecurityOAuth2AutorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                                  PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService accountUserDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        inMemoryUserDetailsManager.createUser(new User("user", passwordEncoder.encode("secret"),
                Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"))));

        return inMemoryUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.approvalStoreDisabled()
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .userDetailsService(accountUserDetailsService)
                .reuseRefreshTokens(false);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password").scopes("openid")
                .authorities("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_EMPLOYEE")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust", "openid")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60*60*8);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/account/userInfo", "/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jwt-authserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>jwt-authserver</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and a login page like below:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap-theme.css}"/>

    <title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form role="form" action="login" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.js}" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

in this way you have a complete authorization server oauth2 that use JWT token even if it can to seem a too big effort it is in my opinion the correct way pleas do not use custom security protocol or path because those will became very soon hard to maintain and complex to fix security issues use a standard security protocol is always the best way!

on the client side you can implement by your self a web sso using the authorization code  or password oauth2 standard flow or using Spring cloud security on the client application using the WebSSO capabilities with a simple configuration like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
class OAuth2SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and().httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

I hope that it can help you